# jQuery validation is not working.. can youtell me this code is right or wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im using jQuery validation, the validation is working properly but after fill the field  click submit button always shows its not a valid form alert msg.. but all the field is filled..
i dont know why is restricted to submit..

anyone tell me why?

Can you tell me anything mistake in my code????

fiddle code is here..

[Fiddle code is here..](https://jsfiddle.net/joelshah/gzvnm50t/)

Here is my code..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#contactForm').validate({
    rules: {
      accountName: {
        required: true
      },
      narr: {
        required: true
      },
      debit: {
        required: true
      },
      cashactcode: {
        required: true
      }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      alert('valid form');
      return false;
    }
  });
  $('#cashSub').on('click', function() {
    $('#contactForm').valid();
    alert('its not a valid form');
    return false;
  });

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- jquery validation cdn -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.2/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.2/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.19.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<form id="contactForm">

  <div class="table-wrapper">
    <div class="table-scroll">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-hover order-list" id="tab_logic">

        <tbody>
          <tr id="fst_row" class="form-group">
            <td>
              <select class="form-control sel_sel required" id="payacc" name="actname" for="actname" value="">
                <option value="">Select TDS A/c name</option>
                <option value="1">TDS A/c 1</option>
                <option value="2">TDS A/c 2</option>
                <option value="3">TDS A/c 3</option>
              </select>
            </td>
            <td class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control price required" id="pay_narrat" name="narr" for="narr" data-toggle="modal" maxlength="200" data-target="#narratModal" placeholder="Enter your text here" />

            </td>

          </tr>

        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-4 vocSub" style="margin-bottom: 0px !important;">
    <div class="col-md-12 cashform_submit" id="">
      <input type="submit" class="btn add-btn submit-btn load cashmainBtn" id="cashSub" />

    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `valid` method returns whether the form is valid. You are calling it and then showing the alert whatever happens.
The code should be:

```js
$('#cashSub').on('click', function() {
    if ($('#contactForm').valid()) {
        // do a thing here with the form data (it is valid)
    } else {
        alert('its not a valid form');
    }
    return false;
});
```

Here is [the documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/) for the function. As you can see it returns `Boolean`.